# Weird Problem with Classes and Optional Arguments

Tags: python

Okay so this was driving me nuts all day.

Why does this happen:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bla = {}):
        self.task_defs = bla
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(str(self.task_defs))

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.task_defs['BAR'] = 1
print 'B is ==> %s' % str(b)
print 'A is ==> %s' % str(a)
```

Gives me the output:

```
B is ==> {'BAR': 1}
A is ==> {'BAR': 1}
```

I know it has to do with python passing everything by reference.

But why does this happen? This was literally making me go insane all day, basically causing me to tear my stuff apart. Shouldn't python be smart enough to deal with something like this?

Comment: Should this be considered a dupe?  There's been lots of questions/problems people have had based on using a default mutable data type.

Comment: Here is one, just an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Just an aside: there's no need to `''.join` a string (you create a single string with the `str` call).

Comment: I voted to close the question, sorry i didn't realize others existed. I read the other topic and it makes more sense :)

Comment: @uberjumper no worries, it's VERY common problem that people run into.

Comment: Though I want to note that I'm not 100% committed to marking dupe.  There are a lot of different questions that all have the same answer so I'm not sure whether or not that should count as a dupe.  I just wanted to discuss to see what other people think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have `bla` initially set to a mutable type (in this case a dict) in the arguments, it gets shared since `bla` doesn't get reinitialized to a new dict instance for each instance created for `Foo`. Here, try this instead:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bla=None):
        if bla is None:
            bla = {}
        self.task_defs = bla
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(str(self.task_defs))

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.task_defs['BAR'] = 1
print 'B is ==> %s' % str(b)
print 'A is ==> %s' % str(a)
```

Comment: Yeah i know but that becomes very messy when dealing with constructors that require multiple optional arguments.

I don't know i am just more or less frustrated that i wasted so much time on something like this. :(

Comment: It's nothing about multiple optional arguments. The problem is that you are using a mutable default, in this case the dictionary.

Comment: No but if i have multiple optional arguments, lets say 5 optional arguments, that take lists/maps, then this becomes a fairly big pain. I think python should just fix it :)